# What's the difference between rm and empty trash?

Tags: command-line, trash

If I put a file in the trash and "empty trash", is that the same as doing `rm file`?

I understand that there are questions here asking about (e.g. [[1]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156655/why-is-emptying-the-trash-so-much-slower-than-rm) [[2]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170066/trashing-trash-and-emptying-trash) [[3]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90026/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-with-rm-rf-trash-from-finder) [[4]](https://superuser.com/questions/506370/emptying-the-trash-takes-forever-is-using-rm-r-safe-to-use-in-mac-os-x-10-7) [[5]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195555/how-can-finder-empty-trash-more-quickly-than-rm-rf-volumes-foo-trashes-501)), but no answer directly pertains to the difference in process (if there is one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `rm` removes the file as does moving it to trash and then emptying the trash. One nice thing about moving files to Trash is that it gives you a little longer to decide if you really want to delete them. `rm` will remove immediately.

Comment: `rm` does *not* prompt by default (except in special cases, like files you don't have write permission to). If you want it to prompt, use `rm -i`.

Comment: well it prompts me a lot if I don't use the -f option.  maybe its what you said but if I use -f then i'm never bothered with the confirmation. I never use -i.

Comment: That's really strange. Do you have an alias for `rm` or something like that? If not, what's the exact prompt you get when deleting a normal file?

Comment: `rm` doesn’t prompt by default (unless you don‘t have write access to the file you want to delete), that part of the answer is dangerously wrong.

Answer (score -1):

> If I put a file in the trash and "empty trash", is that the same as doing rm file?

Effectively yes, although the details may vary under the hood. In both cases, the file can no longer be recovered except under certain circumstances<sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files), [3](https://www.howtogeek.com/361816/how-to-recover-deleted-files-on-mac/), [4](https://www.easeus.com/mac/mac-data-recovery-resource/recover-mac-deleted-file-from-trash.htm)</sup>, or perhaps using forensic [data recovery techniques](https://www.educba.com/data-recovery-techniques/).

That said, I'd like to offer this as an [adjunct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjunct):

I've always liked the concept of "moving to trash" because it gives you a second chance. When I started with Unix systems, I was always nervous about using `rm`... still am in fact.

And so I was very pleased when I found the [`trash` utility for macOS](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/14fedc316441c350b382528ea64bc09c) by [*dabrahams*](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams). There was an [extensive discussion here on moving files to the Trash folder from the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/how-to-move-files-to-trash-from-command-line), and IMHO, this one was the best.

Old habits die hard, and so I created an alias - if I enter `rm`, `trash` is called. If I'm feeling cocky, and really wish to `rm` - I have another alias for that.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `rm` is significantly faster, especially for directory structures, and that `rm` (maybe combined with `sudo`) can remove files which aren‘t removable with „Empty Trash“.